# Converting JSON data to a list view results in an error of A value of type 'List<XXX>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

### **Background**

I have the following JSON data that is being remotely retrieved via an async request, that I'm trying to build a list view out of in Flutter.

```
[
  {
    "loggedin": "0"
  }, 
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "excerpt": "",
    "thumb": "Image 1.jpg",
    "threadid": "1",
    "fid": "1",
    "commentcount": "1",
    "postdate": 1
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Title 2",
    "excerpt": "",
    "thumb": "Image 2.jpg",
    "threadid": "2",
    "fid": "2",
    "commentcount": "2",
    "postdate": 2
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Title 3",
    "excerpt": "",
    "thumb": "Image3.jpg",
    "threadid": "3",
    "fid": "3",
    "commentcount": "3",
    "postdate": 3
}
]
```

### **What I've done so far**

Using this site: https://app.quicktype.io
I've created the following model:

```
List<News> newsFromJson(String str) => List<News>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => News.fromJson(x)));

String newsToJson(List<News> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class News {
  News({
    required this.loggedin,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.excerpt,
    required this.thumb,
    required this.threadid,
    required this.fid,
    required this.commentcount,
    required this.postdate,
  });

  String loggedin;
  String id;
  String title;
  String excerpt;
  String thumb;
  String threadid;
  String fid;
  String commentcount;
  int postdate;

  factory News.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => News(
    loggedin: json["loggedin"] == null ? null : json["loggedin"],
    id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
    title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
    excerpt: json["excerpt"] == null ? null : json["excerpt"],
    thumb: json["thumb"] == null ? null : json["thumb"],
    threadid: json["threadid"] == null ? null : json["threadid"],
    fid: json["fid"] == null ? null : json["fid"],
    commentcount: json["commentcount"] == null ? null : json["commentcount"],
    postdate: json["postdate"] == null ? null : json["postdate"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "loggedin": loggedin == null ? null : loggedin,
    "id": id == null ? null : id,
    "title": title == null ? null : title,
    "excerpt": excerpt == null ? null : excerpt,
    "thumb": thumb == null ? null : thumb,
    "threadid": threadid == null ? null : threadid,
    "fid": fid == null ? null : fid,
    "commentcount": commentcount == null ? null : commentcount,
    "postdate": postdate == null ? null : postdate,
  };
}
```

### **My Question**

When I try to use this data I get the following error:

```
Error: A value of type 'List<News>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
```

What I'm doing in a separate Class is as follows:

```
Future<void> get fetchData async {

    var daUrl = 'https://mywebsitethatservesthejson.com';

    final response = await get(Uri.parse(daUrl));

    if (response.statusCode == 200)
    {
      try
      {



        final decoded = json.decode(response.body) as dynamic;

        decoded.forEach((data) {
          //data is a Map
          if(data.containsKey("loggedin")) {
            _isLoggedIn = int.parse(data["loggedin"]);
          }

        });



        _map = newsFromJson(response.body);
        _error = false;
      }
      catch(e)
      {
        _error = true;
        _errorMessage = e.toString();
        _map = {};
        _isLoggedIn = 0;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      _error = true;
      _errorMessage = 'Error: It could be your internet connection';
      _map = {};
      _isLoggedIn = 0;
    }

    notifyListeners();  // if good or bad we will notify the listeners either way

  }
```

The problem is popping up because of the line

```
_map = newsFromJson(response.body);
```

Comment: what is the type of _map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared your `_map` variable as `Map` or `Map<String,dynamic>`. That's why you are facing this issue

> Error: A value of type 'List' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Since, the return type of `newsFromJson(response.body)` method is `List<News>` and `_map` is declared as `Map`.

Comment: thanks that seems to be the problem-- Do you know what I should declare _map to be?  I don't know how to declare an empty List<News> to accept my data?

Comment: you can write `List<News> _list = []`